# Trying to create a new index on ElasticSearch with node js, and I got. Failed to parse value [5] for setting [index.number_of_shards] must be <= 3

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Implementation:

```
es.indices.exists({index: 'teste'}, (err, res, status) => {
            if (res) {
                console.log('index already exists');
            } else {
                es.indices.create( {index: 'teste'}, (err, res, status) => {
                console.log(err, res, status);

            })
          }
        });
```

And this is the error I'am getting on my request.

```
Erro: status: 400,
api_1    |   displayName: 'BadRequest',
api_1    |   message: '[remote_transport_exception] [Do300lB][10.244.0.93:9300][indices:admin/create]',
api_1    |   path: '/rerun',
api_1    |   query: {},
api_1    |   body: undefined,
api_1    |   statusCode: 400,
api_1    |   response: '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[Do300lB][10.244.0.93:9300][indices:admin/create]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Failed to parse value [5] for setting [index.number_of_shards] must be <= 3"},"status":400}',
api_1    |   toString: [Function],
api_1    |   toJSON: [Function] } { error:
api_1    |    { root_cause: [ [Object] ],
api_1    |      type: 'illegal_argument_exception',
api_1    |      reason: 'Failed to parse value [5] for setting [index.number_of_shards] must be <= 3' },
api_1    |   status: 400 } 400.
```

Does anyone know what exactly it means?. I've tried to google it, but I didn't figure any possible solution.